# MySQL strange behaviour for comaprison operator (!=/<>) i.e. NotEqualTo

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I am using simple `WHERE` clause to fetch records from a table using `NotEqualTo` comparison. Ironically it doesn't return recrods where column has **no value at all**.

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL<>'Something'
```

Above query will return all records where COL isNotEqual to Something, however, It doesn't return those where COL is **empty** or **NULL**.

Why is that so?

It should return records where COL is empty/null as it still satisfies the condition that it isn't equal to 'Something'

Comment: It doesn't return the values where `col` contains `NULL`, because that is how SQL works.  You need to learn about `NULL` values and SQL.  MySQL documentation is a good place to start:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html.

Comment: It's not empty, it's `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Okies thanks guys for helping me out. I didn't know about this behaviour. For others to handle this issue, I modified query as below to get required results:

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL IS NULL OR COL<>'Something'
```

Comment: Note : Empty String is not same as `NULL`

Comment: @Sadikhasan: true that, so my query will still return empty Cols, right?

Comment: Yes because of your condition `COL<>'Something'` which true for empty string

Answer (score 0):

Check [Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) for arithmetic comparison.

> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL.

Check [<kbd>**SQL Fiddle**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/40312)