# Strange MySQL behaviour for comparison

Tags: php, mysql, null

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508660/mysql-strange-behaviour-for-comaprison-operator-i-e-notequalto) that might explain what I am getting as result. But still it seems an odd behaviour.

We have a table filled with supplier products, it gets updated each day (new data read from an xml). A column 'updated' gets a new datetime value during the process. Products that disappear from the supplier xml file should be marked EOL in the column 'flag'

After the import from the xml file I run following SQL to try and find products which should be marked EOL.

```
SELECT * FROM `app_supplier_products` WHERE `flag` != 'EOL' AND `supplier_id` = 1 AND `updated` < '2014-12-29 07:15:01'
```

However this returned no rows. If we altered the time to 07:15:15 we did get results. It seemed as if the smaller than comparison did not return rows from another day.

After doing some other tests we managed to get it working with following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `app_supplier_products` WHERE (`flag` IS NULL OR `flag` = 'MODIFIED') AND `supplier_id` = 1 AND `updated` < '2014-12-29 07:15:01'
```

The flag column can, at this point, be NULL, MODIFIED or EOL. In the future we might add other possible values. This means that we'll have to update all queries when we add another value.

Why doesn't the first query return the expected rows ?

Comment: Does `(flag IS NULL or flag != 'EOL')` work?

Comment: Or how about `NOT (flag <=> 'EOL')`? See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to for the null-safe equal operator.

Comment: `(flag IS NULL or flag != 'EOL')` does indeed work as expected. But I thought NULL was seen as 'not set', 'emtpy' ... So why do we need to do the check explicitly :( Uptill now my life was like 'write less, do more' :)

Comment: `NULL` is special, any comparison with it returns `false`, except the null-safe equal operator. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: You could change the column definition to `flag NOT NULL DEFAULT ''`. Then it will be an empty string, and behave normally in comparisons.

Comment: But than rows where ``flag` = 'MODIFIED'` should have in the results, no?

Comment: Yes, they should be in the results. I guess the only rows with `flag = 'MODIFIED'` were between 7:15:01 and 7:15:15, so changing the time found them.

Comment: Nope that's the strange bit I guess.. We've got MODIFIED in rows from 2014-12-25, they didn't show up.

Comment: 2014-12-25 is not before 2014-11-29.

Comment: Ah, no. I typed it wrong in the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM `app_supplier_products` WHERE NOT (`flag` <=> 'EOL') AND `supplier_id` = 1 AND `updated` < '2014-11-29 07:15:01'
```

This uses the [*null-safe equality*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) operator, so it will match rows where `flag = NULL`.

If you can't use this operator, you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM `app_supplier_products` WHERE (`flag` IS NULL OR FLAG != 'EOL') AND `supplier_id` = 1 AND `updated` < '2014-11-29 07:15:01'
```

Comment: This should be my prefered solution. However We're using this CodeIgniter ORM library which does not support these kind of comparison.

Comment: I used the second one. Thanks for the help. And I damn whoever decided to use NULL as default in all columns...